# Symfony 3. How can I overwrite [config] [fos_user] [registration] [form] for two different bundles using FosUserBundle?

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

In all the overwrite examples I have found, the solution is:

> (app\config\config.yml)

```
fos_user:
...registration:
......form:
.........type: (my bundle form class)
```

They suppose to overwrite for a single bundle, but i have two different bundle form.

Comment: I don't think FOS UserBundle is set out for this as you can only define one form to be used by it. Is the bundle a hard requirement for you? I find that most use cases you can easily implement with Symfony without using the FOS UserBundle.

Comment: The shown configuration is needed to customize forms inside FosUserBundle, not forms inside your bundles. Of course, if your bundles are extending forms from FosUserBundle, this is affecting also your own bundles. If you need to register different types of users, you'll probably need something like https://github.com/PUGX/PUGXMultiUserBundle

Comment: Thanks to both of them, I have finally chosen the Massimiliano solution.